# How to import module dynamically in python with importlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

In python 3.6.2 I am trying to import a module with `importlib`. I am able to import the module directly as:

```
from scripts import config_A_2
```

but when trying with `importlib` as follows

```
module = importlib.import_module('config_A_2', 'scripts')
```

I get an error

```
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config_A_2'
```

Maybe I am using `importlib` in a wrong way?

Info: Its a Mac...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relative import:

```
importlib.import_module('.config_A_2', 'scripts')
```

Or an absolute one:

```
importlib.import_module('scripts.config_A_2', 'scripts')
```

Comment: For the first suggestion I get an error `SystemError: Parent module 'scripts' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
`.

Comment: The second suggestion seems to work. Seems awkwardly complicated for python!! Maybe I create a wrapper for simple use ;-)